# Preventing script injection in asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, regex, code-injection

I have a major question to ask.

I am building my website and it is going really well, however there are many forms that get written to my database and at a later stage the data gets displayed else where within the website so the question is of script injection attacks. What way do you work with it and which is best?

I have several ways of going about this, tested and working but which way

1st) Using ValidateRequest="false" and then server.htmldecode() to decode something like

```
<script>alert("Hello")</script> to 
&lt;alert&gt;(&quot;Hello&quot;);&lt;alert&gt;
```

and that's all great. It goes into the database encoded but when I output it back to the screen the browser re-renders it and then it displays the alert which is not what I want. Even if I use server.htmldecode()

2nd) I have written a class but is it crude and it will need developing further but there I can parse a string though the class and it will removing html tags from the string and return the amended string.

3rd) Remove the ValidateRequest="false" (so it is true) and within the web.config add in an error control which will redirect to another page (with parameters) upon capturing a "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client" event (or any error).

I have tried the Microsoft Anti-Cross Site Scripting library but I could not get that to work. I have also tried RegEx too in many ways and forms but without any success.

So how do you do it on your websites?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: I have since htmlencoded it before outputting it to the screen. That seems to keep all the "&lt;alert&gt;(&quot;Hello&quot;);&lt;alert&gt;", but still your thoughts please.

Comment: have you tried Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment(YourString)?  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/617043/Hack-Proof-Your-ASP-NET-Application-From-Cross-Sit

Comment: Deepu, I will try it again and let you know.

Comment: Deepu, that worked, thanks. Seems a lack of documentation on the net about this library. Can you whitelist or blacklist certain tags?

Comment: Well, You can find in MSDN or stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

Having trying what Deepu says I have made the following. Maybe of use to others.

```
Public Class Encode

Public Function htmlEncode(html As String) As String
    Dim newhtml As String = Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment(html)
    Dim posstart As Integer
    Dim posend As Integer

    For l = 1 To newhtml.Length
        posstart = InStr(l, newhtml, "<", CompareMethod.Text)
        posend = InStr(l, newhtml, ">", CompareMethod.Text)
        If posstart <> 0 And posend <> 0 Then
            newhtml = newhtml.Remove(posstart - 1, posend - posstart + 1)
            l = 0
            posstart = 0 : posend = 0
        End If
    Next

    Return newhtml
End Function

End Class
```

So in VB, you can use class and use the following ...

```
Dim doEncode as New Encode
Dim newHTML as String = doEncode.htmlEncode("<script>alert('Hello');</script><b>Hello</b>")
```

This result of newHTML string will just be "Hello"

Why? because the class will use the Microsoft Sanitizer class to remove any harmful tags and the rest of the class will strip any tags with < > between then. Yes, this will remove 
 and

etc but I do not think it will be much more difficult to make a white-list within this class.

I hope you find this useful and I will try and improve this class in the future as I build my project.

Enjoy